# convert Checkbox into radio button using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to convert checkbox into radio button which is working partially , but not deselecting previous selected radio button.I am looking solution to show one button at a time as a selected.

```
var layers = {
    'Esri_WorldImagery': Esri_WorldImagery.addTo(this.baseMap),
    'World_Topo_Map': World_Topo_Map//.addTo(this.baseMap)
};

var layerHtml = '<ul class="fa-ul">';
for (var key in layers) {
    if (layers.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        var state = this.baseMap.hasLayer(layers[key]) ? 'checked="checked"' : '';
        //layerHtml += '<li><label><input type="checkbox" ' + state + ' value="' + key + '" >' + key + '</label>';
        layerHtml += '<li><label><input type="radio" ' + state + ' value="' + key + '" >' + key + '</label>';
    }
}

layerHtml += '</ul>';
var widget = $('<div id="layer-control" class="sidebar-widget">' + layerHtml + '</div>');

widget.on('click', 'input[type="radio"]', function (e) {

    var was_Active = $(this).prop('checked');
    var value = $(this).val();
    if (was_Active) {
        layers[value].addTo(self.baseMap);
    }
    else {
        self.baseMap.removeLayer(layers[value]);
    }
});
```

Comment: you have already given the element as `radio`, the only thing you need to do is to add a name attribute to all the radio button, and make sure you have given a same name for the buttons which are needed to be toggled

Comment: I need  'Esri_WorldImagery' should be selected by default but when I will select another option , 'Esri_WorldImagery' get deselect and select another option

Comment: Aswin, I added name attribute ,but still not working for me , could you plz suggest me using code?

Comment: Was my answer working for you? It would be nice to have some feedback.

Answer (score 1):

First, regarding the current code with `radio` elements, as *@Aswin Ramesh* has told you, yo should add the `name` attribute. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio#Defining_a_radio_group):

> A radio group is defined by giving each of radio buttons in the group the same name. Once a radio group is established, selecting any radio button in that group automatically deselects any currently-selected radio button in the same group.

Besides the shape (circle vs square) that's the only difference between the `radio` and `checkbox` elements. So consider that checkboxes that behave like radio buttons might be confusing for the user.

That said, if you really want to replicate that functionality on checkboxes, use JavaScript to deselect all the elements but the one which raised the `click` event.

```js
$('#checkboxes').on('click', ':checkbox', function(e) {
  $('#checkboxes :checkbox').each(function() {
    if (this != e.target)
      $(this).prop('checked', false);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="radios">
  <input type="radio" name="rOptions" value="radio1" checked>
  <input type="radio" name="rOptions" value="radio2">
  <input type="radio" name="rOptions" value="radio3">
</div>

<div id="checkboxes">
  <input type="checkbox" value="checkbox1" checked>
  <input type="checkbox" value="checkbox2">
  <input type="checkbox" value="checkbox3">
</div>
```

*Note*: you forgot to close the `<li>` tags.